# Using Mac Excel, How can I delete complicated duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm running Mac Office 2011 under Lion.

I have a spreadsheet with headers of Company, Name, Last Name, City, State, and Email. Some are duplicate entries but are missing the email. I would like to remove the duplicates that are missing Emails and keep the ones that *do* have emails.

Is it possible to make that distinction? If so, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort all the entries by the column with emails, you will end up with all your records stacked by the ones which have empty emails on top of the ones that have an email.

Once you have this, highlight all the records without an email, top to bottom.

Data->Remove Duplicates, and select which columns you would like to remove duplicates on.